# phonegaps facebook connect plugin not working with IOS -- no callback

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

When I try to login using facebookConnectPlugin.login I don't get a call back.  My app switches over to the facebook app then switches back to my app and my app restarts. No error messages or call back.

I've tried requesting "public_profile" permission and "email" permissions

I'm using ios 7.12.

My app is signed with a development certificate instead of a distribution, now sure if that matters. And is compiled with phonegap build 3.6.3

The same code works for android as expected.

If you've seen this before or have suggestions on how to troubleshoot let me know.